# Vs code: Intellisense is not working with numpy

Tags: numpy, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Intellisense is not working with [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) in [vscode](/questions/tagged/vscode) . It is correctly working with other module as [matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib). The problem is illustrated with picture.
[image: no suggestion from intellisense]

Uninstalled and reinstalled code.

Comment: restart vs code, If this doesn't work, try restarting your PC

Comment: did you install [the python extension pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) following [the user docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python#_install-python-and-the-python-extension)?

Comment: It's solved by changing the intellisense version to the preview version.

Comment: To confirm, do you mean switching to the pre-release version of [the Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)? Or what do you mean by "preview version"?

Comment: Yes, I changed the Python extension of  Vs-code to the pre-release version.